# Renaming files in a directory based on an instructions file

Tags: linux, redhat

I have a directory that regroups a .sql file and multiple data files.

```
/home/barmar/test.dir
├── database.sql
├── table1.unl
├── table2.unl
├── table3.unl
├── table4.unl
├── table5.unl
└── table6.unl
```

The .sql file contains an unload instructions for every .unl file the issue I have is that the names of the .unl files are not the same as the instructions on .sql.

Usually the name should be TABLE_TABID.unl Im looking for a way to retreive the names from the .sql file and rename the .unl files correctly.

The .sql file contains multiple instructions here's an example of the lines that contain the correct names.

```
{ unload file name = table1_89747.unl number of rows = 8376}
```

As you can see the only thing in common is the table name (table1) in the example

The expected result should be something like that:

```
/home/barmar/test.dir
├── database.sql
├── table1_89747.unl
├── table2_89765.unl
├── table3_89745.unl
├── table4_00047.unl
├── table5_00787.unl
└── table6_42538.unl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` line will generate commands to rename files like `table1.unl` to names like `table1_89747.unl`:

```sh
sed -n 's/.*name = \([^_]*\)\(_[^.]*\.unl\).*/mv '\''\1.unl'\'' '\''\1\2'\''/p' <database.sql
```

*Assumptions: spaces exist around the `=` sign, and the filename is of the form `FOO_BAR.unl`, i.e. the underscore character and the extension are always present.*

Sample output:

```sh
$ echo '{ unload file name = table1_89747.unl number of rows = 8376}' | sed -n 's/.*name = \([^_]*\)\(_[^.]*\.unl\).*/mv '\''\1.unl'\'' '\''\1\2'\''/p'
mv 'table1.unl' 'table1_89747.unl'
```

To generate **and** execute the commands:

```sh
eval $(sed -n 's/.*name = \([^_]*\)\(_[^.]*\.unl\).*/mv '\''\1.unl'\'' '\''\1\2'\'';/p' <database.sql | tr -d '\n')
```

Goes without saying, before running this make sure your `database.sql` doesn't have malicious strings that could lead to renaming files outside the current directory.